# TYPO3: Problems importing v8 T3D into v11 - Section not found

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-11.x

i got the task to setup a new TYPO3 v11 Installation and to import the Page tree from the old v8 Installation.

The Import itself is working (except for the cms-impexp commandline) but after the import the pages are not editable as they show a 503 error and the Message Section Configuration not found.

Does anybody have a clue on what is going wrong here and what i can do to access the page content?
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: what did you do exactly? and what's the error message?

Comment: I just exported a page tree with all tables, relation and static relations into a T3D File.

The Message i get is 

ERROR 503
Section Configuration not found

Comment: Not a direct solution but maybe a workaround - can you set up a dev TYPO3 8 and import the tree here and 1) check if the problem persists. Then, if it doesnt 2) update that dev installation up to 11 and export from there to the new system

Comment: As there are a lots of changes between the versions you should do the upgrade steps before moving the data to an instance with another version.